# How can I copy files from my local computer to a remote server which I connected to using a Jump Server

Tags: linux, ssh, command-prompt, putty, remote-desktop

I connected to a server (a "jump" server) using the Remote Desktop application on Windows. After entering the Jump Server, I connected to the second server using Putty. How can I copy files from my C:/.... to the final server. I only have a basic knowledge of navigating through folders on command prompt using commands like cd, dir, ls, pwd, etc. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy file to "jump" server. And then use WinSCP program to copy those files to remote linux server.

Comment: Hi, Yuriy. Thank you so much. It really helped. I had to transfer an entire folder containing installation files for a software. But now, Winscp says that the file is too large and can't be installed. How can I go about installing this program on a remote server?

Comment: I think you need devide you file into several smaler peaces (for example using zip archiver) and then on destination linux machine unzip it.